# Xcode "unrecognized selector sent to instance"

Tags: ios, iphone, cocoa-touch, ios7, xml-parsing

get in the way an error message but can not find the error. Can anyone help me?

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"ErgebnisseCell";
    ErgebnisseCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];


    if (indexPath.section == 0) {

    NSDictionary *aktion = self.wmXMLParser.alleAktionen [indexPath.row];
    __block NSString *VP= @"";

    [aktion enumerateKeysAndObjectsUsingBlock:^(id key, id obj, BOOL *stop) {
        if (VP.length) {
            VP = [VP stringByAppendingString:@","];
        }
        VP = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@ = %@", VP, key, obj];
    }];

    cell.spielpaarungLabel.text =  VP;
```

Comment: Post full error message please. There should be class name

Comment: Or code line, where error occurs.

Comment: It means your instance has no such method. Check if you send message to wrong instance. For example, the current should be [A aMethod], but you call [B aMethod]. It sometimes occurs when using collection without checking.

Comment: I am pretty sure error is in line `NSDictionary *aktion = self.wmXMLParser.alleAktionen [indexPath.row];` and the problem is that `self.wmXMLParser.alleAktionen` is not of type `NSArray`.

Comment: self.XMLParser.alleAktieonen is not a NSArray but a NSMutableArray.
Here is the complete error message.

Comment: 2014-02-22 17:17:12.348 Info[2486:70b] -[UITableViewCell spielpaarungLabel]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x10b8c2630
2014-02-22 17:17:12.350 Info[2486:70b] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[UITableViewCell spielpaarungLabel]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x10b8c2630'
*** First throw call stack:

Comment: After this line terminates the debugger. " cell.spielpaarungLabel.text =  VP;".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks to me as if you need to set the cell type in your storyboard.  It's currently set to UITableViewCell and not ErgebnisseCell, and hence doesn't have a spielsparungLabel property.

Answer (score 0):

The cell being return from the method

```
[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];
```

Is not of type ErgebnisseCell, therefore won't respond the

```
spielpaarungLabel
```

Method.

Make sure that you have set the cell's identifier to "ErgebnisseCell" in storyboards or Nib file

Comment: Hello,
that was exactly my problem. In the storyboard I have the Custom Cell not assigned.
But now I have a new problem. The label "spielpaarungLabel" is not filled with data, although the string "VP" data has (see the Log).

Comment: This are the Log data:2014-02-23 14:10:12.346 Info[4010:70b] Brasilien : Kroatien = Spielpaarung,0 : 0 = Ergebniss,12 = Identifier,12.06.14 = Spieltag1
2014-02-23 14:10:12.347 Info[4010:70b] Brasilien : Kroatien = Spielpaarung,0 : 0 = Ergebniss,12 = Identifier,12.06.14 = Spieltag1
2014-02-23 14:10:12.347 Info[4010:70b] 13.06.14 = Spieltag2,13 = Identifier,0 : 0 = Ergebniss,Mexiko : Kamerun = Spielpaarung

Comment: Did you connect the IBOutlet in your custom cell's class to the Label in interface builder?